# Eclipse indexing file (.pdom) is 29GB - how to manage it

Tags: c++, eclipse

My project consists of thousands of C++ files and after many 'out of memory' from the indexer errors, I finally have it all indexed; it's now 29GB.

I have several questions/issue:

***Backup***

Once, when Eclipse crashed, it corrupted the .pdom and I had to restart the indexing. If I make a backup of the .pdom and move it to a diff folder, can I restore a corrupted indexer database by simply replacing the corrupted .pdom with the backed-up one?

In the folder `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.core`, there are the following files

1. project_name.1461683934892.pdom
2. .log
3. project_name.language.settings.xml
4. language.settings.xml

*I may encounter more issues (like cache and speed of 'go to definition'). If so, I'll update this post*

Comment: "project consists of thousands of C++ files": break your project up into independent libraries.

Comment: @RichardCritten that's not an option for me.

Comment: I've seen the indexer use 30GB+ when trying to index Visual Studio 2013 include headers. When I removed it from the paths in Eclipse the problem went away. However, some of the C++11 types are not recognized properly by Eclipse.

Comment: @JamesAdkison that's not what's happening here. I'm only indexing what's in my source folder.

Comment: Okay. I haven't seen your issue then, even though I use Eclipse with a very large project (i.e., 2000+ `.h` and 2000+ `.cpp` files).